# What's wrong with Imgur? Why can't I upload any images?

Tags: support, status-completed, images, imgur

[Imgur](https://imgur.com/) is having some trouble I guess.

I can't upload any images on Stack Exchange.

It looks they have some maintenance issues.

[image: Screen dump displaying Emergency maintenance: We're currently experiencing issues with certain images appearing as a blank page. Nothing has happened to these images, we're just having trouble getting them to you. However, you should not have any trouble uploading new ones. Everything should be fixed soon, so please stay tuned for updates.]

Comment: imgur is also the main picture uploads site for Reddit and I've noticed imgur have been over capacity recently. I've seen a few error messages recently over the past few days. (Although, saying that, I was under the impression the i.stack.imgur was on a different dedicated server, so it's possibly a network capacity problem).

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I've disabled image uploading until this is fixed.

Comment: @balpha, would it be possible to prevent image insertion at the moment? This will drive editiors mad when this blows over and they need (or want) to move everything under the i.stack umbrella.

Comment: @tombull89: When image uploading is disabled (it is at the moment), people can only put an image URL into the dialog. I don't see a reason to disable images altogether.

Comment: Informing them of their typo is a consideration...

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment people who can't see their storage is running low can't be expected to have proper grammar as well.. :)

Comment: Well, typo fixed and message has been changed. Wonder when it will be fixed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Imgur's upstream provider is having storage issues. They're keeping us updated and will let us know as soon as the issues are fixed. Until then, we've disabled image uploading (meaning that you'll only get the good ol' "enter image url" dialog when clicking the image button in the editor, instead of the upload dialog).

**Update:** Should be back to working now, at least for `stack.imgur.com`. Image uploads are re-enabled.

Comment: Just a headsup, you might want to disable it on chat too

Comment: This is going to lead to some issues after being fixed... such as long-term storage of images uploaded with other services, etc.

Comment: @balpha - Can we have a list (not sure if SEDE is up to the job) of all images uploaded in the past 9 hours to move to stack.imgur.com?  I know I uploaded one, and I'll go fix it now, but it would be nice to move the rest in a semi-automated fashion.

Comment: It's happening again, yay.